# Pi 4 B does not use its dot local address

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, raspberrypi

My Pi 4 B is not using the `.local` address I have set it up to use.  I would like to connect my Pi across the network using its `.local` address (such as `pie.local`).  I am really just interested in having the domain be the IP address.

I have tried [this answer posted on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16903/193429) and tried modifying `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` but neither of these work.

I have also tried the three steps listed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1076469/967170), but they do not work.

I can ping my Pi's IP address just fine, but the `.local` address does not resolve.

Neither the Pi nor other devices on the network resolve `pie.local` when pinged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that the package `avahi-daemon` has fixed this issue.

I was also able to change the name to `pie.local` instead of the default one by modifying `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` and restarting the Pi.