# Temporary failure in name resolution/ 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, dns

I have configured a windows VM as my DNS server and configured all my ubuntu VM's to use it.

`netplan` from my ubuntu VM

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
      - 172.0.1.51/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 172.0.1.34
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 172.0.1.29
  version: 2
```

Name resolution/DNS lookup works fine for external internet connectivity.

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from seu35a21-eu-g67.2e345.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=107 time=27.4 ms
64 bytes from seu35a21-eu-g67.2e345.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=107 time=26.6 ms
64 bytes from seu35a21-eu-g67.2e345.net: icmp_seq=3 ttl=107 time=26.7 ms
```

However I added a manual DNS A Record in my windows DNS server in the configured zone(home.local)
`172.0.1.45 nginx.home.local`
From my windows VM, ping to the local FQDN works fine.

```
C:\Users\JCGHDX>ping nginx.home.local

Pinging nginx.home.local [172.0.1.45] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.0.1.45: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.0.1.45: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.0.1.45: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
```

However on my ubuntu VM

```
$ ping nginx.home.local
ping: nginx.home.local: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

```
$ resolvectl status
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (ens160)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 172.0.1.34
       DNS Servers: 172.0.1.34
```

Any pointers why DNS lookup fails for local domain ?

Comment: Just a thought. Can you try putting a dot at the end? Like this: `ping nginx.home.local.`

Comment: @FedKad Tried it. Same issue: `ping: nginx.home.local.: Temporary failure in name resolution`. One interesting thing is reverse lookup is able to identify FQDN
`nslookup 172.0.1.45 45.1.0.172.in-addr.arpa      name = nginx.home.local.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for detailed explanation: [Ubuntu 18.04 .local domain dns lookup not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068131/ubuntu-18-04-local-domain-dns-lookup-not-working)

TLDR; `/etc/resolv.conf` points nameserver to 127.0.0.1#53 which rejects DNS lookups for `.local` domain. Fix is provided in that answer.  However it requires config change in all my ubuntu VM's.

Easy alternate would be configure a new zone in my windows DNS without ending with `.local` and add manual A records to that zone.
Then finally used the FQDN obtained from the zone which works!