# 18.04 in local network as NAS/Headless

Tags: networking, 18.04, server

At the moment, I just want to use my spare desktop as a storage space. I have a few doubts

1. How to access the server machine over the WiFi network ? It has no monitor, mouse or keyboard connected to it. But has a WiFi adapter and runs 18.04.
2. I would like to find some way to `put and take` files from the server. Mostly media files. And a few document files.
3. The whole set up is meant for my main machine which is running out of space and runs 18.04. Once the file transfer is done, I need to find some way to shut down the server from the main machine.

Kindly help with these.

Edit :

I found the solution for 1 and 2. I now need to find out how to shut down the server PC from my main PC. Both Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks.

Comment: How can I install `openssh-server` ? `sudo apt install openssh-server` ? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I would need some time to try. Currently, my only requirment is to shut down the server desktop from my main 18.04 machine. Just wondering if there is any GUI method available. The whole set up is within my home wifi network. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have named your computers `main` and `spare`, where `main` is your `main` computer running out of space, and `spare` is your headless NAS.

## Step 1: Install `openssh-server`

`ssh` stands for secure shell. It is one of the key means of controlling a headless server remotely. Open a terminal in the computer `spare` and use the command:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

to install the ssh-server in your headless server computer.

## Step 2: Test `ssh`

Now open a terminal in `main` and type the command:

```
ssh username@spare.local
```

where `username` is the username of the `sudo` user of the computer `spare`. If username in `spare` is identical to username in `main`, then you can ommit `username@` and can just enter:

```
ssh spare.local
```

If `ssh` to `spare.local` does not work then try the local IP address instead:

```
ssh username@192.168.x.y
```

Your local IP address may look different. x and y are numbers.

Answer the question about trusting the host and enter the `sudo` password for the `spare` computer. If all goes well you will be logged on to the computer `spare` while sitting at the computer `main`. You will know this by the change in the command prompt of the terminal from:

```
YourUserName@main:~$
```

to:

```
YourUserName@spare:~$
```

If you see this change in your terminal, congratulations! Now you can exit `spare` by typing `exit`. Your command prompt will return to:

```
YourUserName@main:~$
```

The test is complete.

## Step 3: Turn off `spare`

Use the following command to turn off `spare`:

```
ssh -t username@spare.local "sudo systemctl poweroff"
```

This command sends the command inside the quotation marks to `spare`. Since that command starts with `sudo` you will be asked for your `spare` password twice, once for the `ssh` command, and the second time for the sudo to power off.

## Step 4: Write a script

You can create a little script so that you don't have to type all that every time. The script can be called `stopspare.sh` and it can be saved in `/home/$USER/bin` folder of your `main` computer. The `/home/$USER` is your `Home` folder, `$USER` is your user name. If the `bin` folder does not exist in `Home`, create it.

The script will have two lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t username@spare.local "sudo systemctl poweroff"
```

Remember to change `username` to the user name you use in `spare`. If you save the script in the location I suggested above, you can just open a terminal in `main` and type

```
stopspare.sh
```

to turn off the spare computer.

## Bonus!

See the **Ubuntu to Ubuntu** section of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310180/how-to-share-files-through-the-local-network/310201#310201) for how to use `ssh` based `sftp` in `nautilus` to access files in `spare`.

You may also want to read [How to harden an SSH server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server) for more about security of `ssh` server.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I have upvoted. I will try this and update.

Comment: I am unable to find anything like this under `Home`  : /home/$USER/bin

Comment: Stuck here : `$ ssh spare@spare-PC.local
ssh: connect to host spare-PC.local port 22: Connection timed out`

Comment: I am able to ping each other through local IP.

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: OK. Let's use IP address then. We will figure out why `spare-PC.local` is not working in another question answer later.

Comment: See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244865/ubuntu-server-not-resolving-lan-hostnames) about not resolving LAN hostname to start troubleshoot the problem with `spare-PC.local`.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried Google, the answers were `sudo ufw allow ssh` or `sudo ufw allow 22`. I didn't try both because I was not sure whether it is safe to use it.

Comment: Since `ssh` with local IP address works, `ufw` is not active.  None of the `ufw` commands will solve the local host name resolution problem.

Comment: Should I enable it ?

Comment: Thar is up to you and what other reasons you may need it for.

Comment: Everything is fine now except during transfer, I get " connection timed out error ". I am forced to  `exit` and reconnect. I am not sure whether the transfer is corrupted or not. Happens mostly with transfers that take a couple of hours or more.

Comment: Best ask a new question about transfer timeout. Indicate which protocol and how you set it up in the question.

Comment: Started a new question :  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203041/connection-timed-out-while-file-transfer-in-headless-nas-18-04