# Connection timed out while file transfer in headless/NAS 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, ssh, samba

Ref : [18.04 in local network as NAS/Headless](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202625/18-04-in-local-network-as-nas-headless)

I got a `spare PC` which I access from my `main PC` ( both running 18.04 ) through Samba folder share. I access the `spare PC` through Nautilus. I can now transfer files from the `main PC` to `spare PC` through Nautilus. I did it with help from the link given above.

Everything is working fine. But the transfer speed through the WiFi network is slow. So it takes some time for transfer if the files have a few GBs in size. The last one took 6 hours. In between, I noticed that the transfer was not happening after some 3-4 hours. The message said `connection timed out`. The only method that could resume the transfer was to `exit` through SSH and login again.

But I believe the `connection timed out` and then the re-login process has got the transfer corrupted. Perhaps some files are missing from the folder and the ISO which actually had 2 GB size was showing only 968 MB. I need to ask

1. How can I avoid spare PC going idle so that there is no connection timed out error ?

I would like to keep the transfer uninterrupted.

2. How to make sure that the interruption is not corrupting the file transfer ?

Thanks.

Comment: Will I have to install `sftp` now ?

Comment: Tried, it says > Unable to access location: connection failed

Comment: Yes. Same with that as well.

Comment: I am lost for now.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong. It should have worked. Sorry.

Comment: It 's ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is the problem solved now? If so, please consider answering your own question, so that it helps others. if you think the solution is trivial or unrelated to Ubuntu, then please delete the question.

Comment: I am working on it. Will need some time before I can confirm that it works. I will post an answer once done.